error when using confint() on fitted gamlss
i have an error occurring in R whenever i want to use the function confint() on a fitted gamlss model (Dagum distribution):

confint(model_dagum_m)
Error in optimHess(betaCoef, like.fun) :
non-finite finite-difference value [13]

Do you know why the error is occurring and what could be done to circumvent it?
Many thanks,
Maria

it's hard to tell without a sample of the data or the model you're using, if you could submit an example, I think it would be easier to help.
Maybe using the function traceback(max.lines = N) after you get this error can also be of some help to debug.
